# Using conditional statements for CPLEX resolver

Tags: optimization, ampl, content-delivery-network

Is it possible to use in AMPL conditional statements such as "if (...) then..."? Below is shown as I tried to do.

```
subject to c1a {k in K, o in O, n in N: n!=t[k,o]}:
sum{e in E}
   (a[n,e]*x[e,k,o]) -
sum{e in E}
   (b[n,e]*x[e,k,o]) =
            (if (r[n,k]==1 and f[n,o]==1) 
                then d[k,o]*(1-f[k,o])
                else 0);
```

My ampl returning to me bug as follows:

```
CPLEX 11.2.0: Constraint _scon[1] is not convex quadratic since it is an equality constraint.
```

Do you have any idea ho to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `if-then-else` expression with CPLEX if the condition (the expression between `if` and `then`) doesn't contain variables. CPLEX also supports so called "indicator constraints" (see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http://www.ampl.com/INFORMS06.pdf&ei=s1KOUffcCa3sigKejICABg&usg=AFQjCNH5QMLgpgltDbwu-86Qt7eEiah8nw&sig2=JsPw7BSnKeitrFeOHCJrew&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE) for more details) which use implication operator (`==>`) and are somewhat similar to `if-then-else`, but allow variables in the condition.

Regarding your example, it is not clear which names correspond to variables and which to constraints but the error suggests that the problem is not due to `if-then-else`, but because you have a quadratic constraint in the form not supported by CPLEX (see the section Quadratic Constraints on page 33 of [ILOG AMPL CPLEX System User's Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CF0QFjAD&url=http://www.netlib.org/ampl/solvers/cplex/ampl110.pdf&ei=6lOOUbWsL4eTiAL5toCYDw&usg=AFQjCNH4l09V2he28mqHj_DLFIyPNZLm6A&sig2=gE3PCnjKKInXMHNmi3S51Q&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE) for the information about the accepted form).

Comment: short info: indicator constraints only support binary variables

Answer (score 1):

you may change your solver cplex only deal with convex and quadratic constraints and it's used byt default in Ampl resolution, so you can try to repload your mod and dat files and then choose another solver as follow:

```
ampl: option solver " ipopt";
ampl: solve;
```

or

```
ampl: option solver " couenne";
ampl: solve;
```